"Command not found: mosh-server" when trying to connect to macOS server running mosh
I'm trying to connect to an M2 Mac mini with mosh.
However, when connecting with mosh <hostname>, I get an error zsh:1: command not found: mosh-server:
$ mosh <username>@<hostname>                                     
(<username>@<hostname>) Password:
zsh:1: command not found: mosh-server
Connection to m2-mini.local closed.
/opt/homebrew/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message. (Have you installed mosh on your server?)

I definitely have installed mosh on that server. When I ssh in, and run which mosh-server I get /opt/homebrew/bin/mosh-server:
<username>@<local_hostname> ~ % ssh <username>@<remote_hostname>
...
<username>@<remote_hostname> ~ % which mosh-server
/opt/homebrew/bin/mosh-server

A workaround is to run:
mosh corneliusroemer@m2-mini.local --server /opt/homebrew/bin/mosh-server

but this shouldn't be necessary?
Interestingly, when I run a remote command with ssh -t, I get "mosh-server not found":
<username>@<local_hostname> ~ % ssh corneliusroemer@m2-mini.local -t which mosh-server
(<username>@<remote_hostname) Password:
mosh-server not found
Connection to <remote_hostname> closed.

What's going on here?
Update:
This might have to do something with the type of shell that's loaded. I get for example:
$ ssh <username>@<remote_hostname> -t 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin


On Apple Silicon , the Homebrew bin directory isn‘t in the default PATH. To fix, add a file homebrew to /etc/paths.d containing /opt/homebrew/bin.
To make it work in the current shell, restart it. For ssh it will work straight-away.

For some reason, homebrew wasn't added to the path in non-interactive shells.
To fix it, run on the server:
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv 

or add the following to your ~/.zshenv:
# Homebrew path support
if command -v /opt/homebrew/bin/brew >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
fi

Note: This assumes you have an ARM Mac (M1/M2/M3...). On Intel, you need to replace /opt/homebrew with /usr/local.

I was surprised that brew didn't have itself set up correctly from the start - maybe I had used an unconventional installation. Good idea to run brew doctor, I forgot that!

@CorneliusRoemer Define "correctly" first, then submit a PR to Homebrew.
